# Why play console shows less download than actual?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-play-console

My Android app uses Firebase Authentication(Gmail+phone). When I see the new users signed in to Firebase authentication and compare it with Google Play Console 'new User acquisition' then Play console always shows less number than Firebase shows(with registered Gmail or phone number). What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play uses robots to test and review your app. These robots do not show in the Google Play Console but show in Firebase. That is why you see more users in Firebase than Google Play Console.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I also appreciate your point to some extent. But we have emails with phone numbers of the users who signed in and it is true that all are from my local region, not from google. That's why I am confused with this download number.